# Privileged scopes not accessible

Tags: uber-api

We are integrating the Uber API into an app that is still in the development phase and not quite ready to go through the privileged scope request process. The [API documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/introduction) states that "During development, your account (and any developer accounts you list on the dashboard) will be able to authorize these [privileged] scopes without whitelisting."

However, it seems that we are unable to access these privileged scopes at the moment, even just for development purposes. Can someone help us understand why this might be the case? We have put together a document with screenshots and commands to help illustrate the issue, which we can share via email if someone from the Uber API team is kindly able to help. Thanks!

Further information:

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

REQUEST:
https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests
-H  ‘Accept-Language: en_US’
-H  ‘Content-Type: application/json’
-H  ‘Authorization: Bearer ’

Payload
{
                "fare_id": "d30e732b8bba22c9cdc10513ee86380087cb4a6f89e37ad21ba2a39f3a1ba960",
                "product_id": "a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d",
                "start_latitude": 37.761492,
                "start_longitude": -122.423941,
                "end_latitude": 37.775393,
                "end_longitude": -122.417546
}

RESPONSE:
Status: 401: Unauthorized

{
"message": "This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: request.delegate.tos_accept, request, request.delegate",
"code": "unauthorized"
}

As shown above the request API call is returning unauthorized status and appears to require Privileged Scope for accessing it.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you need to authorize the privilege scopes by enabling them for your app in the dev dashboard and then passing them during the [oauth authorize stage](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/introduction#authorize).

Comment: Thank you, Dustin. Can you please explain exactly how we can “authorize the privilege scopes by enabling them for your app in the dev dashboard”? When we go to the Authorizations screen in our dev dashboard (https://developer.uber.com/dashboard/app/..)  and look at the Privileged Scopes at bottom of the page, all the scopes we need (all_trips, requests, request_receipt) are grayed out and can’t be selected. Is this normal? How can we "enable" them? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes, you can enable them for the user that owns the app or has been invited via the dev dashboard. The users can be issued a token for the app by passing the list of space delimited scopes via the scope param to the oauth authorize endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, Dustin. We're still confused as to what needs to happen, given that I'm the user that owns the app and our developer, who has been invited, is also having trouble. Could we send you an email with the doc that contains a detailed explanation of the problem? It has screenshots, commands, etc.

Comment: See the auth guide (https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/introduction#authorize). When authorizing a user you need pass the scopes you want access to via the scope parameter. Example: https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&response_type=code&scope=request%20profile

Comment: Thanks, Dustin! This explanation was helpful and we have figured out the authentication process. We appreciate your time and patience here.

Comment: What is the login url if am using the sandbox environment? Can i use login.uber.com if am using the sandbox environment?

Comment: The authentication endpoints are the same, but you can use the token with sandbox-api.uber.com to facilitate a sandbox ride.

Comment: @Dustin - I am up to the same point and same challenge as lcronk. What is the syntax to " pass the scopes you want access to via the scope parameter"